# Should this bickering question be deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34877/hired-developer-insists-on-doing-things-the-wrong-way) question started out so-so, but by the time you get to the comments on the last (most downvoted) question, it's descended into a mire of tit-for-tat insults between two people who have ended up using Programmers to settle an internal dispute.

Whatever the merits of their respective cases, or the value of the original question, and even taking into account the time invested by answerers and commenters, I can't help thinking that this question ought to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I think that *answer* should be deleted, and I have done so. The question seems OK so far.

Comment: I closed it as not constructive as it's not the first time it's been an issue and the answers are referencing the activity in the deleted questions, but if you think it's okay, I've reopened it.